# Add different default and custom tags to Visual Studio XML Documentation

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, xml-comments, xml-documentation

I am just learning how to use the XML documentation capabilities in visual studio and C#.

The default XML tags used in the documentation are "summary", "param name", and "returns".

I'd like to add "remarks" to the default tags.  I'd also like to add custom tags.

I've looked through MSDN, the XML documentation tutorials, and stackoverflow and haven't found the way to do this.  Any suggestions are much appreciated, and thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 3):

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/96188fd3-957c-4526-a1de-cf3c2bc7be1d) describes a solution for VB, but says that it is not available for C#.  Follow the links to vote to have this feature included in the next version of Visual Stuido.

Comment: Can we get an update on this? Is it still not supported by C#?

Comment: The UserVoice issue is still open and from the comments it sounds like VS still doesn't support it. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2709987-xml-comments-schema-customization-in-c-

Comment: Looks like the request has been closed now, with 500+ votes on it and without any explanation.

Comment: This answer is outdated, the [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lisa/2010/05/24/how-to-customize-the-xml-comments-that-are-inserted-by-the-visual-basic-code-editor/) referred to is broken